# Naming a SOAP web service endpoint address

Tags: web-services, soap

I am developing a SOAP interface and am having trouble deciding what to name the endpoint address.

Options:

```
- {soap,api,service,???}.foo.com.au
- www.foo.com.au/{soap,api,service,???}
```

What are the typical names that a SOAP service gets?

Comment: I have always felt that "John" is a good name. I suggest you name it `john.foo.com.au`, since `john` should always be at the top.

Answer (score 1):

I would use `www.foo.com.au/soap`, mostly because it's an easy way to tell people that it's a SOAP service, and if you want to add a REST service later, you can use `www.foo.com.au/rest`

Answer (score 1):

Keep in mind, in practice, all solutions are technically equivalent. The benefits of one naming system over another are only at the ease or understanding what the URLs are about (for humans), or maintainability, really. So, if you are searching for a standard we can tell, at best:

- If you have a big company with lots of applications, go for the  `http://api.company.com/application/rest` and/or `http://api.company.com/application/soap` approach

  - Reason: you can separate, right from the start (networkwise) the web service servers (http://api.srv.com/app) from the *human* web browsing servers (http://www.srv.com/app).
  - All applications have one big root "meeting" point (the root URL `api.company.com`), so if anyone wonders what is company-wide available, just check `http://api.company.com` and it can list all services available.
- If your setup is not that big, it is probably not worth the trouble, so don't fear using the `www.`. But keep in mind it's best to use at least a different context, such as `api/`, so that anyone knows right off the bat a service URL is about a web service(!): `http://www.company.com/application/api/rest` / `http://www.company.com/application/api/soap`

Note: It's also common to use `service`, although `api` seems to be somewhat better descriptive (`api.something.com` leaves no doubt about what that page is about).

Some examples (as you can see, there is really no global standard):

- Google's search API: http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/services/search/web?v=1.0&q=test
- Twitter's search API: http://search.twitter.com/search.json?q=w00t
- Facebook' Graph API: http://graph.facebook.com
- Facebook' Dialog API: http://www.facebook.com/dialog (see, no standard even **within** facebook!)
- Weather Gov SOAP forecast: http://www.weather.gov/forecasts/xml/DWMLgen/wsdl/ndfdXML.wsdl

Buy many seem to keep the good ol' *company-wide* APIs "*meeting points*":

- http://developers.google.com
- http://developers.facebook.com
- http://dev.twitter.com